# Address for Excel table cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table `HP_175` that has headers one of which is `NOx`. In a cell outside the table if I start a formula (=) and click on the header cell I get this address.

```
=HP_175[[#Headers],[NOx]]
```

How do I address the cells in the rows in the NOx column?

I tried replacing '#Headers' with a row number - didn't work.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reference the seventh row (including the header),

```
=INDEX(HP_175[[#All],[Nox]], 7)
```

To reference the seventh row (not including the header),

```
=INDEX(HP_175[Nox], 7)
```

Comment: If I don't need the data table features like sort and filter should I be using an Excel Table instead of a Data Table (if those are the correct names?)

Comment: That would depend on more circumstances than I am aware of. Frankly, I very rarely use than as I prefer to use xl as a raw and calculated data repository instead of a word processor or presentation software app.